# HashMap containsKey() cannot find the String key I have put. The String key's value is from reading a text file

Tags: java, hashmap, key

In my program, I have defined a hashmap as follows:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> dictionary = new  HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I have to read from a text file, and put the first word I read (which is "whoo", BTW) as a String key to my hashmap, with 1 as a value. I also put another one with a key of "dummy" and value of 2 to the hashmap

```
try{
    File f = new File("test.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    String word = "";

     word = sc.next();

     dictionary.put(word, 1);
     dictionary.put("dummy", 2); 

     System.out.println("contains whoo as key: " + dictionary.containsKey("whoo")); 
     System.out.println("contains dummy as value: " + dictionary.containsKey("dummy")); 

 }
 catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("error");
 }
```

now my problem is that "whoo", the String key that I have read from my text file, cannot be found from the hashmap's keys. On the other hand, the "dummy" that I directly put as a String key can be found in the hashmap's keys.

[image: what the program prints when I run the code]

I need a way to be able to make containsKey() find "whoo" because my program relies on file reading and using the words read as String keys to the hashmap. Thank you!

EDIT:

this are the contents of the text file I'm reading:

[image: text file]

I did what most of you suggested and tried to print out the value of word first

```
System.out.println("word read is: " + word);
```

And also added another kind of check to see what keys do my hashmap contain

```
Set keys = dictionary.keySet();

for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
    String key = (String) i.next();
    System.out.println("key found in the hashmap: " + key);

}
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

Even though the String word contains "whoo", and is even found in the set of keys, containsKey() still gives me a false

Comment: I think that you'll need to post a valid [mcve] along with a small version of the text file and observed vs. expected output in order to get decent answers.

Comment: If the string isn't found in the map, then "whoo" isn't being read from the file.

Comment: You really need to learn using a debugger, or at least add logging statements to your code. Check what the value of word is. Check what your map contains.

Comment: Is the String `whoo` has all characters in lower case ? in file also see if it does not have space. Better use debug or print the value.

Answer (score 0):

Print your `word` variable before adding it to the dictionary. Better, add a breakpoint and debug. I expect you'll find it is not the value you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

The program looks pretty straight forward to output the result as true while reading from the file. Check for whitespaces, commas or case used. I believe that might be the issue.

As suggested by others, using a debugger and printing out the contents would definitely help you track down the root cause.